# IIS uses proxy for webservice request. How to stop this?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis, proxy

I have a problem with a little .Net web application which uses the Amazon webservice. With the integrated Visual Studio web server everything works fine. But after deploying it to the IIS on the same computer i get the following error message:

```
Ein Verbindungsversuch ist fehlgeschlagen, da die Gegenstelle nach
einer bestimmten Zeitspanne nicht ordnungsgemäß reagiert hat, oder
die hergestellte Verbindung war fehlerhaft, da der verbundene Host
nicht reagiert hat 192.168.123.254:8080
```

Which roughly translates to "cant connect to 192.168.123.254:8080"

The computer is part of an Active Directory. The AD-Server was installed on a network which uses 192.168.123.254 as a proxy. Now it is not reachable and should not be used.

**How do I prevent the IIS from using a proxy?**

I think it has something to do with policy settings for the Internet Explorer. An "old" AD user has this setting, but a newly created user does not. I checked all the group policy settings and nowhere is a proxy defined.

The web server is running in the context of the anonymous internet user account on the local computer. Do local users get settings from the AD? If so how can I change that setting, if I cant login as this user?

What can I do, where else i could check?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Proxy use can be configured in the web.config.
The system.net/defaultProxy element will let you specify whether a proxy is used by default or provide a bypass list.

For more info see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex.aspx

Comment: Adding
    <system.net>
      <defaultProxy enabled="false" />
    </system.net>

to the web.config did the trick for me.

Comment: you can also run proxycfg -d at the command line to ensure that all winHTTP applications run without using a proxy on the computer.

Comment: what changes need to be done in Web.config file - for only one page test.aspx to use the proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Some group policy settings that may be relevant:

*Root \ Local computer policy \ Computer configuration \ Administrative templates \ Windows components \ Internet Explorer \ Make proxy settings per-machine* -- by default this is disabled, meaning individual users on the server have customised proxy settings.

*Root \ Local computer policy \ User configuration \ Windows settings \ Internet Explorer maintenance \ Connection*. In "Automatic Browser Configuration" the value "Automatically detect configuration settings" -- you can set this off to prevent the process trying to detect proxy settings automatically.

That said, using the defaultProxy setting as shown in hwiechers' answer would seem to be a better way of doing it, not affecting other processes or users on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

IIS is a destination.  The configuration issue is in whatever is doing the call (acting like a client).  If you are using the built-in .Net communication methods you will need to make the adjustment inside of ... Wait for it ... Internet Explorer.

Yep!  That little bugger has bitten me more times than I care to remember.  I used to have to switch the proxy server settings in IE 5 or 6 times a day as I switched between internal and external servers.  Newer versions of IE have a much better "don't use proxy server" set of rules.

-- Clarification --
As it seems that the user ID used by IIS is using this setting, you'll probably need to search the registry for where the proxy information is stored for each user ID and/or the default.